# ERROR TypeError: this._document.createElement is not a function angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new of Angular and I am using Angular Materials. I am getting follow error for mat-select. My code is as follows

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Owner Type">
       <mat-option value="Individual">Individual</mat-option>
       <mat-option value="Corporate">Corporate</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And the error is :

```
ERROR Type Error: this._document.createElement is not a function
at n._createHostElement (main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1)
at n.create (main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1)
at n._createOverlay (main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1)
at n._attachOverlay (main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1)
at n.ngOnChanges (main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1)
at main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1
at main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1
at eu (main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1)
at ju (main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1)
at main.6b5485aaca2669c7d428.js:1
```

Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"@angular/animations": "^7.2.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.0",
"@angular/common": "^7.2.6",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^7.2.6",
"@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
"angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^2.2.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"datatables.net-bs4": "^1.10.19",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"ng-pick-datetime": "^5.2.6",
"rxjs": "^6.4.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"},
```

"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"  }

Please someone assist me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you close your `<mat-form-field>`? Your example doesn't. You get the error when you try an AOT compilation?

Comment: Yes, I closed </mat-form-field>

Comment: @KartikS Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue even i am importing the observable as "reza Torkaman Alhamdi" suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It may be cause of way you are importing `Observable`.

instead of this `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'`; try this one: `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'`;

Comment: Thank you for reply. I did same thing but still facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

simply add an array in ts file such as 
ownerType = ["Individual", "Corporate"];
and then add the following in app.module.ts

```
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
@NgModule({
   imports: [ ..., MatSelectModule, ...]
})


<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Owner Type">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let owner of ownerType" [value]="owner">
      {{owner}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the third party plugin for date and time picker plugin in this application, and it was conflicting with all materials. Now I uninstalled date and time picker plugin, and it is working fine now.